# WPF. Check and disable a checkbox if another checkbox is checked

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding

I have 2 checkboxes.
when one is checked, the other one must be checked and disabled.
The code I have so far is like so

Xaml

```
 <CheckBox x:Name="chkSABranches" Content="Apply to all branches" IsChecked="{Binding IsSABranches,ElementName=pgPageTemplate}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

In xaml.cs:

```
 public static DependencyProperty IsSABranchesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSABranches", typeof(bool), typeof(pgAccounts), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public static DependencyProperty IsSAWarehousesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSAWarehouses", typeof(bool), typeof(pgAccounts), new PropertyMetadata(false));

  public Boolean IsSABranches
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsSABranchesProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsSABranchesProperty, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSABranches");
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSAWarehouses");
            }
        }

 public Boolean IsSAWarehouses
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsSAWarehousesProperty) || (bool)GetValue(IsSABranchesProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsSAWarehousesProperty, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSAWarehouses");
            }
        }
```

This doesn't seem to work.. Could anyone please provide some guidance. thanks

Comment: As Sam suggested, doing this in XAML only is perfectly possible and a lot easier with Triggers. Also, you shouldn't put code in the CLR setters of DependencyProperties... That's not how they work. And you don't need to Notify changes of a DependencyProperty since they already do that on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Here how to do it entirely in `Xaml` using `DataTrigers`

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox >
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=CheckBox1}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi,ThanksI actually need to use the dependency property object. COuld you please help me fix the code I have ? tanks